# Selenium not recognising checkbox with complex attribute

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

I have the following checkbox on the webapp I am creating selenium scripts for.
The problem I am running into is that my script can't find this checkbox.

My code:

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(SELENIUMWebDriver.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(
            By.XPath("input[@ng-model=\"model['attributes']['3']['attributes']['38'].value\"]"))).Click();
```

```html
<div class="checkbox" ng-class="{ disabled: form.schema.isDisabled }">
   <label>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="form.schema.isDisabled" ng-change="form.onChange(model['attributes']['3']['attributes']['38'].value, form)" ng-model="model['attributes']['3']['attributes']['38'].value" ng-model-options="::form.ngModelOptions" ng-true-value="::'True'" ng-false-value="::'False'" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty"> 
   <span class="checkbox-label ng-binding" ng-bind="form.title">Registratie EVR/SFH?</span>
   </label>
   <div class="help-block ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="::form.description" ng-bind-html="form.description"></div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong. It seems `//` is missing in your `xpath`. change it to relative `xpath` and try : `By.XPath("//input[@ng-model=\"model['attributes']['3']['attributes']['38'].value\"]")))`

Comment: Even with `By.XPath("//input[@ng-model=\"model['attributes']['3']['attributes']['38'].value\"]"))).Click();` it is not working...

Comment: Explain what do you mean "it is not working"? Update your question with exception log

Comment: @Andersson, selenium doesn't recognise the checkbox. `Exception thrown: 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException' in WebDriver.Support.dll
Timed out after 30 seconds`

Comment: Can you provide some more `html`

Comment: How do you know that? :) What is **exact output** of your code? Do you get `TimeOutException`? Do you actually see this checkbox on the page when browser is opened or you need to scroll down to it? Also check whether it located inside an `<iframe>`

Comment: Yes it is displayed. Yes, I get a `WebDriverTimeoutException`. Yes, it is located inside a `<div>` but even the `<div>`is not unique.

Comment: just provide some more `html` before and after your checkbox element, it will be easy to trace out the uniqueness.

Comment: Update the original post with a more complete html code

Comment: Check my updated answer. Hope It will help

Comment: Also this is not a desirable solution as the 'text' can also vary between English and Dutch..  :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have many checkbox with same `className` try the following using `index`

```
By.XPath("//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty'][@type='checkbox'][1]");
```

**Updated**

```
By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'Registratie')]/preceding-sibling::input[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty'][@type='checkbox']");
```

Comment: this is not good because there are other checkboxes on the same page who also have this 'class' and 'type', so this xpath doesn't make it unique, sorry.  :(

Comment: I don't want make use of an index because the index of the checkbox might change...

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use this xpath?

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Registratie EVR/SFH?')]/preceding-sibling::input
```

I saw that this value can change languages also. If that is the case you could add an "or" into your xpath so either would be acceptable.